# Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting an error when I give

```ts
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = {
            firstName : "test",
            lastName : "test",
            age : 40,
            address: {
                street : "Test",
                city : "test",
                state: "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error (see [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngZS4.png)):

```
Property 'user' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

`user` is instantiated from `User` which is declared in User.ts by this code:

```ts
export interface User {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age?: number,
    address?: {
        street?: string,
        city?: string,
        state?: string
    }
}
```

If I add a question mark (`?`) to `user`, another error appears in some other file (see [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBRwY.png)):

```
Error occurs in the template of component UserComponent.
src/app/components/users/users.component.html:2:44 -
    error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

2 <ul class="list-unstyled" *ngIf="loaded && users?.length > 0">
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Well it isn't initialised or assigned in the constructor, is it? You could avoid that error by *doing that*, rather than in ngOnInit.

Comment: Yeah..But in the course, they said that Constructor is used for injecting dependencies..I still get the second error (in pic 2 in the question) after adding them in the constructor

Comment: I don't know what course you're doing, but it doesn't have to be *exclusively* for that. I had to switch from `ngOnInit` to `constructor` when [turning on strict mode](https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/f9edb0b992764f8d649d3e702ae08b4bf474f3d9#diff-884f7f49640e5923f6bcac4c51d90340330a178f662defbe61e5f5aac1c512de), but all the tests still passed. And it's unclear what you expected in the last two screenshots - 1. making it optional in one place doesn't make it optional everywhere; and 2. if it's optional `users?.length` **is** potentially undefined.

Comment: Ohk...Why is `users?.length` undefined?
I don't want to mention the course name here..It might be against the rules of stack overflow

Comment: It's *potentially* undefined, because if users is optional then users can be undefined, in which case users?.length is also undefined. Why would mentioning the resources you're getting information from be a problem?

Comment: Ohk if it is not a problem, I am learning from Brad Traversy's Udemy course Angular front to Back..I wrote the samd code...I am still getting the same error. I downloaded their file and tried that..It also shows the error but the instructor does not get any error in his code..

Comment: Then you should report it to them, they may not be aware the content has issues. Angular and TypeScript develop over time, those resources might not be up-to-date.

Comment: No one has responded there..So I thought there is some error from my side.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This is caused by TypeScript's Strict Class Initialization.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization

To resolve this issue you must either declare that the type can be both Foo|undefined, or utilize the '!' symbol to indicate definite assignment as per the above documentation:

Case 1:

```js
@Component({...})
export class Component {
  @Input() myInput: string|undefined;
}
```

We indicate that the type may be either a string or undefined.

Case 2:

```js
@Component({...})
export class Component {
  @Input() myInput!: string;
}
```

In this case we utilize the ! symbol to indicate that we are aware that `myInput` is not initialized in the constructor and we will handle it elsewhere.

### Alternate Solution

If you do not care about strict class initialization, you can disable the feature completely in your `tsconfig.json` by adding a flag to your compiler options

```json
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}
```

**Note:** You will have to restart the TypeScript server for the compilerOptions to be reapplied. The easiest way to achieve this is to simply restart your IDE.

Comment: Even if I used `myInput!: string;` when I write `myInput = undefined` I get an error saying `undefined is not assignable to type`

Comment: Right, when you utilize the `!` that is like a promise you make that this value will NOT be `undefined`, which is why the compiler considers it a mistake to assign it undefined. The correct usage would be to simply write `myInput!: string` and ensure it holds a string value before its first usage, even if that is an empty string, such as `myInput = ""`

Comment: MAN!! I've been stuck on this issue for 30 minutes, Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If none of this works, you can try it

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    ....
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    ...

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your course was correct. BUT, I think it is mostly fine to move things from ngOnInit if they are not related to rendering.

IMO, Angular makes a quick rule to avoid some rendering issue but it is not a black and white one. The rule I think it is just trying to make thing simple for new users. And this is a more advance topic.

quote from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24571#issuecomment-404606595

```
For angular components, use the following rules in deciding between:
a) adding initializer
b) make the field optional
c) leave the '!'

If the field is annotated with @input - Make the field optional b) or add an initializer a).
If the input is required for the component user - add an assertion in ngOnInit and apply c.
If the field is annotated @ViewChild, @ContentChild - Make the field optional b).
If the field is annotated with @ViewChildren or @ContentChildren - Add back '!' - c).
Fields that have an initializer, but it lives in ngOnInit. - Move the initializer to the constructor.
Fields that have an initializer, but it lives in ngOnInit and cannot be moved because it depends on other @input fields - Add back '!' - c).
```

I think this is a good guideline

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolve the issue by using the add type to undefined with or-operator or else use "!" symbol in the character like below:

[igame!: IGame;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjX05.png)

[igame: IGame |  undefined;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z76iu.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
put this at you tsconfig.json in compileroption

Answer (score 1):

Please use like this.

```js
user!: User
```

Tip: Please use ! after the variable uninitialized.