# Property 'form' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-microplate',
  templateUrl: './microplate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./microplate.component.css']
})
export class MicroplateComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      columns: new FormControl('some value', [
        Validators.required
      ])
    });
  }

  get columns() { return this.form.get('columns'); }
}
```

Here is my component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <label for="columns"><b>Columns: </b></label>
    <input id="columns" type="text" [formControlName]="columns">
</form>
```

I get the following error message at `form: FormGroup;`:

`Property 'form' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

I have used the information from Angular website, but I cannot solve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">`. The reason is that you creat the form in the ngOnInit, until yet form are undefined. Futhermore is `formControlName="columns"` -without `[` `]`

Comment: @Eliseo, I did what you said but again the same error message.

Comment: Then I should suppose that the problem is your `get columns`. try `get columns(){ return this.form?this.form.get('columns'):null}`. NOTE I just make a stackblitz and it's not necesary the <form *ngIf="form" ...>. The stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q7cj3b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Eliseo, I did the new change that you said, and now I get the error message `Type 'AbstractControl | null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | null'.`

Comment: Mohsen, has you remove the `[]` in formControlName? if you use `[]` Angular consider "columns" as variable, and as you has a variable (really a getter that it's unnecesary in your code) is a FormControl not a string Angular fails.

Comment: @Eliseo, But as I know from the Angular website, this is a convention and required thing. Maybe I do not understand you.

Comment: Really, see my answer and what is the reason to use get columns()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'user' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874221/property-user-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-constru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moshen the reason to use

```
get columns() { return this.form.get('columns'); }
```

Is for do something like

```html
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <label for="columns"><b>Columns: </b></label>
        <!--see that you use formControlName="columns", not between []-->
        <!--you can also use
           <input id="columns" type="text" [formControlName]="'columns'">
            see that in this case is an string, NOT the variable "columns" -->
        <input id="columns" type="text" formControlName="columns">
        <!--here use "columns" that is your FormControl to ask if you has errors and is touched-->
        <div  *ngIf="columns.errors && columns.touched">Required</div>
    </form>
```