# Error with reactive forms Angular, Property 'X' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

I´m trying to make a reactive form for a little form that I want to implement in my project but don´t know why Angular is throwing me this error:

> Property 'formulario' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

This is my code:

**Component file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  public formulario: FormGroup;

  constructor(private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  createForm(){
    this.formulario = this.fb.group({
      nombre: ['', []],
      email: ['', []],
      mensaje: ['', []],
    })
  }

  sendMail(){
    let string = 'mailto:';

  }

}
```

**App.module file:**

```
// Modules

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Components

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { MediaComponent } from './shared/media/media.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NavbarComponent, MediaComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PagesModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In Pages module is also implemented this code line:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

If someone can help me to find the error, I will appreciate it so much!

Comment: do you have 'strict' mode enabled in your project? if so set your `public formulario: FormGroup | undefined`

Comment: @Edward I´ve tried but this error is throwed: `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup  <form autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="formulario"(ngSubmit)="sendMail()">`

Comment: try and see if this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993163/7712755

Comment: @MikkelChristensen I´ve checked the post but is not what I was looking for. The problem is that I can´t understand why is throwing me this error even when I typed that is an `FormGroup` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that your property has no initializer... simple solution would be to refactor your code

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

   formulario = this.fb.group({
      nombre: ['', []],
      email: ['', []],
      mensaje: ['', []],
    })

  constructor(private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  sendMail(){
    let string = 'mailto:';

  }

}
```

I like this approach as the code becomes easy to follow, test and maintain

Comment: It works and I understand why, honestly is easier to mantain it but...why it doesn´t work my previos code? I wish to understand it.