# Property 'listingSub$' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564) please resolve this issue

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, typescript-typings

```js
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listing-detail',
  templateUrl: './listing-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listing-detail.component.scss']
}) 
export class ListingDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  listing!: Listing | undefined;
  listingSub$: Subscription | undefined;
  thisid: string | undefined;
  
  constructor(private listingService: ListingService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.listingSub$ = this.listingService.getListing(this.id).subscribe(listing => {
      this.listing = listing;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use the ['Definite Assignment Assertion'](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) for `listingSub$` property too: `listingSub$!: Subscription | undefined;`. That would effectively disable the compilation error without deactivating strict checking for the rest of the project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874221/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

The error contains the answer. You need the property to always have a value. The solution would be to assign `listingSub$ = undefined` by default.

```js
export class ListingDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  listingSub$: Subscription | undefined = undefined;
  ...
}
```