# Property .... has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm learning Angular reactive forms and I'm running into an error.

Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeeUY6WaXiA I get to the part where he adds `myForm:  FormGroup;` and I get the following error:

`Property 'myForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

Here's my `src/app/components/form/form.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup;  

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      website: '',
      password: ''
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874221/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-constructor/64993163#64993163

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874221/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of the warning by setting `strictPropertyInitialization: false` inside the `tsconfig.json`.
As well as you can add the `!` as a postfix to the variable name as

```
myForm!: FormGroup;
```